# EDIT: How to change [value]row names within a Variable in R

Tags: r, variables, rename

how do I change row names within this variable in my data frame? I would like to change all ActivityHour 00AM 1AM 2AM 8AM 9AM 10AM 11AM 12PM 1PM 2PM 3PM

```
structure(list(Id = c("user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", 
"user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1"), 
ActivityHour = c("0:00", "1:00", "2:00", "8:00", "9:00", 
"10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00"), TotalIntensity = c(20, 
8, 7, 13, 30, 29, 12, 11, 6, 36), AverageIntensity = c(0.333333, 
0.133333, 0.116667, 0.216667, 0.5, 0.483333, 0.2, 0.183333, 
0.1, 0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the variable `ActivityHour`. You are not changing row names which for your example are c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"). This will change the `ActivityHour` variable assuming the data structure you provided is called `example`:

```
hours <- paste0(0:23, ":00")
ampm <- paste0(c(0:12, 1:11), c(rep("AM", 12), rep("PM", 12)))
timetable <- data.frame(hours, ampm)
example$ActivityHour
#  [1] "0:00"  "1:00"  "2:00"  "8:00"  "9:00"  "10:00" "11:00" "12:00" "13:00" "14:00"
example$ActivityHour <- timetable$ampm[match(example$ActivityHour, timetable$hours)]
example$ActivityHour
#  [1] "0AM"  "1AM"  "2AM"  "8AM"  "9AM"  "10AM" "11AM" "12PM" "1PM"  "2PM"
```

Comment: Clever! I couldn't figure out how to get "0AM". Nice one

Comment: Wow! Okay cool I think I got it. so you are creating 0:00 through 23:00 hours and then 00:00 am to 12:00 AM (which by the way should be 00:00 through 00:11 because 00:12   should be PM) and then 1:00PM to 11:00PM. then matching the original activity hour category to the new hour category and assigning the ampm variable to it, essentially?

Comment: Yes. Just change `c(rep("AM", 13), rep("PM", 11)` to `c(rep("AM", 12), rep("PM", 12)`. I've made that change above.